# Natural language de-identification

Tags: nlp

I am looking for a natural language tool that can automatically de-identify English text. For example, every email address should be renamed or obscured. But proper names should be de-identified, as should addresses and what not.

There is a [MITRE Identification Scrubber Toolkit](http://mist-deid.sourceforge.net/). I don't know how well it works.

My questions:

- Are there any other tools out there?
- Does anyone have experience with the MITRE tool? How well does it work?

Thanks.

Comment: @eowl Agreed - named entity recognition + token substitution is principally about named entity recognition.  However, you might also add anaphora resolution.  Being able to identify anaphora ("he", "the official", "the spokesman", etc.) is important in being able to further anonymize text.  Such tools are definitely in the NLP domain, and less about coding (i.e. not so much related to SO as the above SE site).

Comment: (Continued) If this is related to legal or ethical requirements, then you'd do very well to look at what the NLP community can offer, which will be more substantive than simply coding something anew (which could incur new legal liabilities for not using the state of the art resources).  Anyway, this is more tool related than coding, which is a reason to migrate.  Good luck, it is an interesting question.

Comment: @Iterator NLP is still only a proposal, so we can't migrate anything there until it actually becomes a site.

Comment: @eowl Please don't use URL shorteners. A proper link would be a lot clearer and potentially more inviting.

Comment: @anna Ah, I was unaware of that limitation. Darn :( This is perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De-identification (perhaps more often referred to as *anonymization*) is a very active research area as its success is obviously a requirement for the use of authentic text corpora in such fields as NLP for healthcare, medicine and the like. I recommend that you look at the tools listed in the answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/712/data-anonymization-software) on CrossValidated. If you follow the links further, you will find research papers describing how these tools work with further references and results evaluations.